# MySql - Not connecting with the server using MySQL Shell

Tags: mysql-shell

I use MySql for the first time and run into several problems which I tried to solve during hours, but without any success!

The first problem is the following: I tried to connect to a MySQL database (MyDatabase) using mysql commands in the MySQL Shell, but I am encountering syntax errors like this:

```
MySQL  JS > mysql -u root
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'root'
```

```
MySQL  JS > mysql -u root -p
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'root'
```

In the MySql Workbench, I can connect with MyDatabase.

I carefully studied the documentation on MySql (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-disconnecting.html) and as I log in from the same machine, I omitted the host. User (root) and password were double checked and are correct.

I have no Idea what might be the reason for this error? Has anyone an idea? I tried variations like 'MyDashabord' and so on but nothing seems to work!

My system:

- Windows 11
- MySQL Server 8.0.35
- MySQL Workbench 8.0.34
- MySQL Shell 8.0.35

Comment: `mysql -u root` is a command you enter into the Unix shell, not MySQL shell.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql -u root` is a Unix command, not a MySQL Shell command.

The MySQL Shell command to connect to the database is `\connect`. See [MySQL Shell Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html) for full documentation.

```
MySQL  JS > \connect root@localhost
```

You can also specify the connection options when starting MySQL Shell, as described in [Connecting using Individual Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-using-parameters.html)

```
$ mysqlsh -u root
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I really was a blockhead. That saved my evening.